# bringSubviewToFront not showing it's view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my table view controller, I have a button that when I press, I want it to show the map view, so I just did the following. However, for some reason it's not showing up the view... why is this>

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mapViewController = mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction) toggleAction:(id) sender {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:mapViewController.view];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the view as a subview:

```
-(IBAction) toggleAction:(id) sender {
    [self.view addSubView:mapViewController.view];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;

}
```

Then remove it on dismissal (removeFromSuperView).

Comment: what is the different between the bringSubViewToFront?

Comment: bringSubViewToFront will only work if the view in question is already in existence within the subviews array.  You created a viewcontroller but never added its view to the subviews of the current view, so bringSubViewToFront was being called on a view that had not been put anywhere.  addSubView puts the view in the subviews array and, by default, renders it on top.

Comment: ok.. so I need to add and remove view back and forth if I want it to go map view and table view?

Comment: Yup, leave the table view there all the time and add and remove the mapview as a subview of that.